# A property of $C^{0, \alpha}$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, holder-spaces

I am going through $C^{0, \alpha}(\Omega)$ regularity, $\alpha\in (0, 1)$, where $\Omega$ is a regular domain (not bounded, in general).

I can not find much material to study from, but I found this note in which is stated what follows.
Let $f\in C^{0, \alpha}(\Omega)$ with
$$|f|_{C^{0, \alpha}} = \|u\|_\infty +\sup_{x, y\in\Omega, x\neq y} \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{\|x-y\|^\alpha}.$$
An easy property is that there exists $\beta\in (0,1)$ (not necessarily equal to $\alpha$) and a constant $c>0$ such that
$$|f(x)|\le c(1+|x|^\beta).$$

I am not interested in this property for a particular reason, but for the fact that it is stated that is "easy to check" and my trying to prove it since hours unsuccessfully.

I have tried writing $|f(x)|=|f(x)-f(y) +f(y)|$ and then trying to get an upper bound, but it did not work for me.

Does anyone have a better idea? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please share the source of the notes you using?

Comment: @Akira is there any way I can share it with you all? It is a huge PDF file that a classmate shared with me. Many topics are covered in there (essentially of PDEs), but just a few pages about $C^{0, \alpha}$ regularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your line of reasoning, we’re free to choose $y$, so we might as well choose $y=0$. Of course, this assumes $0\in\Omega$; otherwise we can choose something like $y=cx$ for some fixed $c$ such that $cx\in \Omega$. The key is just that $y = O(x)$. Then,

$$\begin{align} |f(x)|&\leq |f(x)-f(0)|+|f(0)|\\ &\leq |f|_{C^{0,\alpha}} |x-0|^{\alpha} + \|f\|_\infty \\ &\leq |f|_{C^{0,\alpha}}(1+|x|^\alpha)\end{align}$$